# How can I administer a VirtualBox Ubuntu server from host OS?

Tags: wordpress

i am setting up LAMP on ubuntu server 10.10 on virtualbox install from a mac osx 10.5 host.
right now, i am using lynx to look at pages in /var/www/
but in setting up wordpress, i am having trouble using lynx to create the wp-config.php file.
i tried changing values in wp-config-sample.php  then copying it to wp-config.php but this didnt work.
so i would like to go ahead and try from the host OS, the virtual network is on 10.0.2.0,
how can i get at this thing from the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Parallels on Mac and VmWare on Windows for do something like that.

I put the virtual host in NAT mode and, for each domain that I create on Apache I write into my host file a redirect to the IP of the VirtualHost, so I have not to use Lynx.

In the same way I create an host entry called vm that point to the same IP of the VirtualHost so I can connect to it via SFTP (with the root or the user login) or SSH (if installed and configured) or just simple FTP.

In this way you can treat the VirtualHost like a real hosted website... or use 'nano' or 'vi' and edit files from the shell :D

You can also be interested in webapp like Webmin for "manage" the entire machine via web.